# Serializing nested objects in DRF

Tags: json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a test object on my website that I am trying to get into the database correctly.
It's an order object with nested product data.
Here's an example of JSON being posted by front-end:

```
{
    "phone": "123456789",
    "first_name": "name",
    "delivery_date": "2020-01-06",
    "delivery_time": 2,
    "address": "address",
    "comment": "comment",
    "payment": 0,
    "order_items": [
      {
        "quantity": 2,
        "pizza": 1
      },
      {
        "quantity": 3,
        "pizza": 2
      }
    ]
}
```

Here's my `serializers.py`

```py
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField()
    pizza = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    print(pizza, quantity)

    def get_pizza(self, obj):
        print(obj.pizza.id)
        return obj.pizza.id

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('quantity',
                  'pizza',)


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    """
    Calculate order_items field 
    """
    def get_order_items(self, obj):
        items = obj.orderitem_set.all()
        print(obj)
        print(items)
        return OrderItemSerializer(items, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('phone',
                  'first_name',
                  'delivery_date',
                  'delivery_time',
                  'address',
                  'comment',
                  'payment',
                  'order_items',)
```

As result, `order_items` is always empty:
`"order_items": []`

I'm using Swagger to test and document API. I can post orders directly from there with no errors but even when I add order items manually, they still don't appear in server response body. Which must mean that I am not processing nested objects properly.

POST

```
{
    "phone": "123456",
    "first_name": "string",
    "delivery_date": "2000-10-21",
    "delivery_time": 2,
    "address": "string",
    "comment": "string",
    "payment": 0,
    "order_items": [
        {"pizza": 2,"quantity": 3},
        {"pizza": 1,"quantity": 4}]
}
```

201, Response body:

```
{
  "phone": "123456",
  "first_name": "string",
  "delivery_date": "2000-10-21",
  "delivery_time": 2,
  "address": "string",
  "comment": "string",
  "payment": 0,
  "order_items": []
}
```

I've also set up some `print` lines in code above, and it looks like `OrderItemSerializer` isn't being used at all.
`get_order_items` prints order id and an empty array, while `get_pizza` doesn't print anything when making an order on the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override serializer's `create()` method to make [writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Try something like this:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    """
    Calculate order_items field 
    """
    def get_order_items(self, obj):
        items = obj.orderitem_set.all()
        print(obj)
        print(items)
        return OrderItemSerializer(items, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('phone',
                  'first_name',
                  'delivery_date',
                  'delivery_time',
                  'address',
                  'comment',
                  'payment',
                  'order_items',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_data = validated_data.pop('order_items')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for item_data in items_data:
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, **item_data)
        return order
```

Also you can just use `OrderItemSerializer` as field without `SerializerMethodField`. You can use `source` argument to specify field [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source):

```
order_items = serializers.OrderItemSerializer(many=True, source="orderitem_set")
```

Comment: Used the same documentation. As far as I understand, `create` works with an array, and my arrays are empty. So I am assuming the problem is in `OrderItemSerializer`.
`print(obj.pizza.id)` isn't printing anything, which means there's no data in the first place.

Comment: @GlebIvanov `print(obj.pizza.id)` isn't printing because related items doesn't saving during POST requst. Did you try to override create method?

Comment: Yep. Tried doing it before, as in docs. Got this: `'Order' object has no attribute 'order_items'.`
Model for OrderItems has foreignkey to Order, so I don't need to add this field to Order, just create objects that have order id in them.

Comment: @GlebIvanov hard to say without actual traceback, but I suppose `'Order' object has no attribute 'order_items'` doesn't related to `create` method. And most likely related to serializer's field. Order models doesn't have `order_items` attribute, it's `orderitem_set` as far as I know according to your code. So using `source="orderitem_set"` argument on serializer's field should fix it. Try to use code from my answer, hope this will work.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't seem to matter if I'm using `source` field. The response I get is `{'phone': 'string', 'first_name': 'string', 'delivery_date': datetime.date(2000, 10, 21), 'delivery_time': 2, 'address': 'string', 'comment': 'string', 'payment': 0, 'o
rder_items': [OrderedDict([('quantity', 3), ('pizza', <Pizza: Chicken>)])]}`. And problem seems to be in that OrderedDict object. Is there a way to unpack it or maybe I should change how it's being generated in front-end?

Comment: @GlebIvanov so now you see order_items in the response? As for `OrderedDict` it's normal django's typo for JSON response. You don't need to do something with this.

Comment: I can unpack it into `[('quantity', 3), ('pizza', <Pizza: Chicken>)]`. And it's weird that it looks like that, cause original JSON sends me a proper dict: `{'quantity': 3, 'pizza': <Pizza: Chicken>}`